# Extracting Google Maps Place Data (specifically gas prices)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I am developing an android app that will take in a fuel range of a vehicle and create a google map of the available gas stations in the area of that fuel range.  I can currently get the place data from the Google Nearby Place Search function to get all the nearby gas stations within a radius but it doesn't seem to have any of the gas price data, similar to what you find when you search google maps from your computer and select a gas station icon.  I want to be able to display the prices with the markers so the user can find the cheapest gas station easier.

Can anyone tell me where I can find this gas price data within the google maps place details?

Is this information a premium data feature or does it just require some more digging into the individual places?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also looking how to get this info from google.

Answer (score 1):

Gas price data is not currently available via any Google Maps APIs, there's no supported way to grab this in a programmatic fashion.  Feel free to file a feature request for the Places API following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/support#issue-tracker).

Answer (score 0):

There you go.

> Price Discovery Every day OPIS captures station-specific retail
>   gasoline and diesel prices for up to 130,000 service stations
>   throughout the United States. Through exclusive relationships with
>   credit card companies, direct feeds and other survey methods, OPIS is
>   able to provide the most comprehensive and accurate pump prices in the
>   industry.
>
> The OPIS retail data is relied on by some of the top companies in the
>   country to provide consumers with the most accurate and timely
>   information available including AAA, Microsoft, Mapquest, America
>   Online, Garmin, Verizon, Sprint and many more.

http://blumenthals.com/blog/2017/02/03/how-do-daily-gas-prices-stay-accurate-in-google-maps-elsewhere/